# More than 6 Limit Lines in Line Chart MPAndroid Chart

Tags: java, android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using Line Chart using **MPAndroid Chart** Library and I want limit lines (in some cases 2 limit lines and sometimes only 1 limit line). Its working fine but I am getting **warning** every time.

> E/MPAndroiChart: Warning! You have more than 6 LimitLines on your
>   axis, do you really want that?

```
        LimitLine line = new LimitLine((float) **VALUE_HERE**);   
        line1.enableDashedLine(20f,8f,0f);
        line1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        line1.setTextSize(9f);
        line1.setLineColor(Color.GREEN);
        line1.setLabel("Cut Off");
        lineChart.getAxisLeft().addLimitLine(line1);
        line1.setLabelPosition(LimitLine.LimitLabelPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM);
```

Any suggestions / solution ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Every time before load the data follow these steps

**step1**

Limitline is xaxis then follow the code

```
XAxis axis= lineChart.getXAxis();//goto step2
```

Limitline is yaxis Left then follow the code

```
YAxis axis= lineChart.getAxisLeft();//goto step2
```

Limitline is yaxis Left then follow the code

```
YAxis axis= lineChart.getAxisRight();//goto step2
```

**step2**

```
axis.removeAllLimitLines();  //your axis.removeAllLimitLines();
```

**step 3:addlimitline**

Add the Limit Line What u want